# Is there a way to create my own helper function in React?

Tags: reactjs

In a several components i have a function returning URL of user avatar:

```
import defaultAvatar from 'assets/images/default-pic.jpg'

class MyComponent extends Component {
  userAvatar () {
    const { profile } = this.props

    if (profile.has_avatar) {
      return profile.avatar
    } else {
      return defaultAvatar
    }
  }
}
```

is there a way to DRY this function between multiple components?

Comment: If you could flatten your props, you could use `defaultProps` to specify a default value for `profile`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## With Default Props

If you make an avatar component that accepts avatar as a top level property, then you can just use default props to specify the value when it's not provided.

```
function Avatar({ avatar }) {
  return <img src={avatar} />;
}

Avatar.defaultProps = { avatar: defaultAvatar };
```

Then render this new component from inside your existing one.

```
return (
  <Avatar profile={props.profile} />
);
```

This way you can keep everything declarative and remove the need for a `has_avatar` property.

## As a Utility Function

But you could also just rip it straight out and fiddle the arguments so you can call it from anywhere.

```
function getUserAvatar(profile) {
  if (profile.has_avatar) {
    return profile.avatar
  } else {
    return defaultAvatar
  }
}
```

Then rewrite your original code.

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
  userAvatar () {
    const { profile } = this.props

    return getUserAvatar(profile);
  }
}
```

## As a Higher Order Component

It would also be possible to implement this as a higher order component.

```
function WithAvatar(Component) {
  return function(props) {
    const { profile } = props;
    const avatar = getUserAvatar(profile);

    return <Component avatar={avatar} {...props} />;
  };
}
```

This would allow you to wrap any existing component with the `WithAvatar` component.

```
function Profile(props) {
  const { profile, avatar } = props;
  return (
    <div>
      <img src={avatar.src} />
      <span>{profile.name}</span>
    </div>
  );
}

const ProfileWithAvatar = WithAvatar(Profile);

render(
  <ProfileWithAvatar profile={exampleProfile} />,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

Passing `profile` as a prop to the outer component causes `WithAvatar` to process it and select the correct avatar, then pass it down as a prop to the wrapped component.

Answer (score 2):

If you've used the `React.createClass` approach you could able to use mixins to share code across components. Since you are using ES6 approach you can checkout HOCs (Higher Order Components)

Reference: https://gist.github.com/sebmarkbage/ef0bf1f338a7182b6775

Comment: It's probably worth mentioning that the React team are converting the docs and examples to using classes with a view to eventually deprecate mixins and `createClass`, so HOCs are probably the way to go.